# Problem in fullCalendar in retrieve the source

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm working on a project as I need to make a schedule for multiple users
while I'm working on the code (.fullCalendar( ‘addEventSource’, source )) this method doesn't bring the source (no response) this source must give me a response as an event

```
$('#'+group).draggable({
  zIndex: 999,
  revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
  revertDuration: 0 , //  original position after the dra
  start: function() {
  //alert($('#array_block').val());
  //create events
  group=  $(this).attr('id');
  //add the conflict time as red color 

  $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource','somepage.php? 
  view='+group );},
  stop:function(ev,ui){
  //on stop drag delete red color 

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource','somepage.php?view='+group 
  );
  },
});
```

I hope that my Q is clear, What I need is the event response.
NOTE: I'm retrieving the event as a JSON.
thank you for your time

Comment: And what happens instead with all that code? Is this after all related to PHP?

Comment: what does your somepage.php?view='+group retrieve and how is it shown when you retrieve it?

Comment: the page retrieve array as json from Database and that array contain id,start,end,title,color

Comment: Why do you add the event source when dragging starts and immediately remove it again when dragging stops? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to view the unavailable time when i start drag the event from external events list then i remove the unavailable time slot from the fullCalendar when drag stop

Comment: Ok. So what does the JSON returned by your server code look like? Please show an example then we can check it is correct. And, have you looked in your browser's network tools to see if the Ajax call is running successfully?

Comment: all of these are working will also the function was work good but when i close the page and comeback to it later it dose not work note that i do not change anything  any suggestion please!!!